# Find largest k-th element through median of medians and partition around k

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

For homework, I am trying to implement the median of medians algorithm to find the *k*-th largest element in an (unsorted) array, and then partition around it so that I can get the *k* largest elements from the array. It seems to work on small arrays but for big arrays (size > 50), it will either generate a runtime error "RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp", or it will never terminate.

What needs to be fixed?

```
def partition(a, p, r, pivot):
    """
    Permutes the elements of a[p..r] (inclusive) in-place:
       first elements <= a[r], then a[r], then those > a[r].
    Returns the new location (index) of pivot value a[r] in the array.
    """
    i = p - 1
    for j in range(p, r + 1):
        if a[j] < pivot:
            i = i + 1
            a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i]

    return i

def mom(a, left, right):
    """
    Returns the median of medians for array a.
    """
    length = right - left + 1
    if length <= 0:
        return
    if length <= 5:
        return sorted(a[left : right + 1])[length/2]

    num_of_medians = length/5
    medians = [mom(a, left + 5*i, left + 5 * (i + 1) - 1) for i in range(num_of_medians)]
    return mom(medians, 0, len(medians) - 1)

def kth(a, left, right, k):
    """
    ~~~~~
    NOTE: k here means k-th smallest element. So in an array of length 10, the
    k-th smallest element is the (len(array) - k)-th largest element.
    ~~~~~

    Partitions the array a around the median of medians pivot. Keeps finding new
    pivots until the pivot == k. Then the partition is around k.
    then a[(len(a) - k)...(len(a)-1)] will output the largest k elements (not sorted)
    """
    pivotIndex = mom(a, left, right)

    pivotIndex = partition(a, left, right, pivotIndex)

    while k != pivotIndex + 1:

        if k > pivotIndex + 1:
            pivotIndex = kth(a, pivotIndex + 1, right, k)

        elif k < pivotIndex + 1:
            pivotIndex = kth(a, left, pivotIndex, k)

    return pivotIndex + 1 #this is index of the kth largest element
```

EDIT: I have found the error: my last line should be `return pivotIndex` and not `return pivotIndex + 1`.

Comment: Please provide some sample input and the actual code you run (i.e. the code that calls `kth()`).

Comment: @Petr I run it by just calling `kth` and filling in values. See edit, it was a one-off error which I have fixed. Thanks!

Comment: Good that the issue is solved, however, in future post the whole runnable code so that others can just copy-paste and run it. Nor I, not, I guess, other users are willing to invent missing code to simply be able to run your example.

Comment: @Petr Ok I understand, will do next time! Thanks for your help